# .NET DateTime difference - has a year passed

Tags: .net, datetime, timespan

I am trying to determine if a year has passed using the following code:

```
bool HasYearPassed
{
    get
    {
        var inception = InceptionDate.Value; // DateTime Value from UI
        var expiration = ExpirationDate.Value; // DateTime Value from UI
        TimeSpan difference = expiration - inception;
        return difference.Days > 365;
    }
}
```

However, in certain scenarios I am getting incorrect answers. Specifically if inception date is 1/1/2014 and expiration date is 1/1/2015, difference.Days returns 365, which fails the test, although a year has indeed passed. Any suggestions to improve the logic?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the definition of "year passed"? What's with leap years?

Comment: Why then `>365` and not `>=365` ?

Comment: Leap years are the problem of course.  Your property getter makes no sense, the difference is always a year.  It is expired when start.AddYears(1) >= now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A solution that doesn't care about leap years:

```
DateTime inception = InceptionDate.Value; 
DateTime expiration = ExpirationDate.Value; 
return expiration.Date.AddYears(-1) >= inception.Date;
```